# Downloading .gpx file returns "No file"

Tags: html, download, gpx

I have created a webpage using RazorPages, where I want the user to be able to download GPX files to get maps of terrains.

The map is also pictured in a PDF file, which I am able to download.
The files are uploaded to this path: wwwroot/assets/products/[productID]/[fileID] which associates the file to the product. I can see that the file is uploaded correctly, as a .gpx file. However, when I try downloading it using this tag:

```
<a href="~\assets\products\5ad37306-e07a-4965-900c-e8559a4142a4\5900223c-c067-4299-a700-a8a958b49117_fells_loop.gpx" download="GPX_file">Download GPX file</a>
```

It downloads an empty .txt file:

[image: Empty .txt file]

By adding .gpx to the download attribute, it downloads an empty .gpx file:

```
<a href="~\assets\products\5ad37306-e07a-4965-900c-e8559a4142a4\5900223c-c067-4299-a700-a8a958b49117_fells_loop.gpx" download="GPX_file.gpx">Download GPX file</a>
```

[image: Empty .gpx file]

I know the file is uploaded correctly, because I can find the file with content in this exact path on my computer, and also in the solution explorer. By opening it, the content is displayed, and I can use the .gpx file.

[image: File in folder]

Every other filetype I've tried works fine (txt, pptx, docx, xsls, csv, pdf, png, jpeg), but gpx seems to be an issue.

What causes this, and how can I fix it, and be able to download gpx files?

Comment: In my original solution I have "/" - copied file path to demonstrate without collecting the name from the DB, and the "~" gets the path to the folder in the solution. This works for every file type in both development environment and in the live environment with an active domain, but not GPX files. For example, I can download the picture and PDF file in the same folder shown in the picture just fine.